# Built ElectronJS project with Sharp node not launching

Tags: node.js, npm, electron-packager, sharp

I've built a desktop app with ElectronJS using the Sharp node for some image processing. Running the project from the terminal with npm start works fine with no issues. When I build the project for desktop users with electron-packager, no matter what OS I try launching it on I get an error that says "Something went wrong installing the "sharp" module". Here's the full error read out on MacOS:

```
Uncaught Exception:
Error: 
Something went wrong installing the "sharp" module

dlopen(/var/folders/m9/h3c8db8n5vg98dn_46_0tb1cj60dj1/T/.com.electron.prototype.ruROOB, 0x0001): Library not loaded: @rpath/libvips-cpp.42.dylib
Referenced from: <8E44C8DA-AB29-314C-9D4D-0E8353480586> /private/var/folders/m9/h3c8db8n5vg98dn_46_0tb1cj60dj1/T/.com.electron.prototype.ruROOB
Reason: tried: '/private/var/folders/m9/h3c8db8n5vg98dn_46_0tb1cj60dj1/T/../.././vendor/8.14.5/darwin-x64/lib/libvips-cpp.42.dylib' (no such file), '/private/var/folders/m9/h3c8db8n5vg98dn_46_0tb1cj60dj1/T/../.././vendor/8.14.5/darwin-x64/lib/libvips-cpp.42.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/cjmagri/Documents/ElectronJS/prototype/prototype-darwin-x64/prototype.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libvips-cpp.42.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/cjmagri/Documents/ElectronJS/prototype/prototype-darwin-x64/prototype.app/Contents/Frameworks/libvips-cpp.42.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS@rpath/libvips-cpp.42.dylib' (no such file), '/private/var/folders/m9/h3c8db8n5vg98dn_46_0tb1cj60dj1/T/../.././vendor/8.14.5/darwin-x64/lib/libvips-cpp.42.dylib' (no such file), '/private/var/folders/m9/h3c8db8n5vg98dn_46_0tb1cj60dj1/T/../.././vendor/8.14.5/darwin-x64/lib/libvips-cpp.42.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/cjmagri/Documents/ElectronJS/prototype/prototype-darwin-x64/prototype.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libvips-cpp.42.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/cjmagri/Documents/ElectronJS/prototype/prototype-darwin-x64/prototype.app/Contents/Frameworks/libvips-cpp.42.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libvips-cpp.42.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libvips-cpp.42.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)

Possible solutions:
- Install with verbose logging and look for errors: "npm install --ignore-scripts=false --foreground-scripts --verbose sharp"
- Install for the current darwin-x64 runtime: "npm install --platform=darwin --arch=x64 sharp"
- Consult the installation documentation: https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/cjmagri/Documents/ElectronJS/prototype/prototype-darwin-x64/prototype.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/sharp/lib/sharp.js:37:9)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1269:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1324:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1124:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:965:12)
at f._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:13330)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1148:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/cjmagri/Documents/ElectronJS/prototype/prototype-darwin-x64/prototype.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/sharp/lib/constructor.js:11:1)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1269:14)
```

I've done a lot of troubleshooting from online forums, but none of the solutions have seemed to work. This includes rebuilding the node with verbose, uninstalling and reinstalling and then also uninstalling vips through homebrew... any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error on linux using electron-builder. What worked for me was adding an entry under asarUnpack: in the electron-builder.yml file

```
asarUnpack:
  - resources/**
  - node_modules/sharp/**
```